# How to make Jest testing work in a React Native (Expo) application that uses Firebase? ("addEventListener and attachEvent are unavailable")

Tags: firebase, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, expo

For the past couple of weeks, I have built a simple React Native application on Expo that uses Firebase Firestore for storing user data.

The basic functions of the app work fine, and now for the purpose of practice, I tried to build some tests to the project as well using Jest. I searched for information on how to make tests with React Native/Expo/Jest, and I mostly followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/@shalomsam/setting-up-jest-in-an-expo-app-thats-using-firebase-b21465fbc3f2

I installed all the dependencies as suggested:

```
npm i jest jest-expo react-test-renderer firebase-mock --save-dev
```

I also modified the package.json as suggested in the tutorial. I also created the mock Firebase component in the "__mocks__/firebase.js" path. Contents of the firebase mock component:

```
import firebasemock from 'firebase-mock';

const mockdatabase = new firebasemock.MockFirebase();
const mockauth = new firebasemock.MockFirebase();

const mocksdk = new firebasemock.MockFirebaseSdk(path => (
    path ? mockdatabase.child(path) : mockdatabase
),
    () => mockauth);

export default mocksdk;
```

I tried to do one simple test for testing that it works.
Content of the test file (App.test.js):

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import import App from '../App'

it('App should render correctly', () => {
   const tree = renderer.create(<App />).toJSON();
   expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

However, I get the following console output when running "npm test":

```
> jest ./__tests__

 FAIL  __tests__/App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    addEventListener and attachEvent are unavailable.

      at goog.events.listen_ (node_modules/@firebase/node_modules/google-closure-library/closure/goog/events/events.js:275:15)
      at goog.events.listen (node_modules/@firebase/node_modules/google-closure-library/closure/goog/events/events.js:183:12)
      at Ek.addStorageListener [as ca] (node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/src/storage/localstorage.js:172:5)
      at Tk.addListener (node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/src/authstorage.js:469:3)
      at new un (node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/src/storageusermanager.js:108:3)
      at new En (node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/src/auth.js:122:7)
      at Object.instanceFactory (node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/src/exports_auth.js:757:16)
      at Provider.Object.<anonymous>.Provider.getOrInitializeService (node_modules/@firebase/component/src/provider.ts:194:33)
      at Provider.Object.<anonymous>.Provider.getImmediate (node_modules/@firebase/component/src/provider.ts:95:29)
      at FirebaseAppImpl.Object.<anonymous>.FirebaseAppImpl._getService (node_modules/@firebase/app/src/firebaseApp.ts:127:54)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.581 s
Ran all test suites matching /.\/__tests__/i.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

package.json content:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "test": "jest ./__tests__",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|sentry-expo|native-base))"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.9.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "expo": "~41.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "firebase": "8.2.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-41.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.4",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.0.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-native-windows": "^0.64.12",
    "undefined": "react-navigation/stack",
    "yarn": "^1.22.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "firebase-mock": "^2.3.2",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "jest-expo": "^42.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Expo version: 4.7.2, NodeJS version: 14.4.0

**Based on the error output it seems to have something to do with Firebase. Apparently mocking Firebase does not still work properly. Still after spending time on this, I don't have a clear idea on what to do next. Perhaps Expo/Jest/Firebase are still not well compatible with each other? Even trying very simple tests (such as 2+3 equals 5) without any Firebase involvement produces the same error output, so this seems to be related to something else than the test content.**

**I would like to have at least simple tests for my project and any help is appreciated! Thanks!**